# How to set up mock with an expression?

Tags: c#, installation, mocking, expression

How should I set up an expression here?

```
[TestMethod]
public void SaveLocation()
{   
    //Arrange
    var dbMock = new Mock<BandItEntities>();
    dbMock.Setup(x => x.Users.SingleOrDefault(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>)).Returns(new User());
    var userAccess = new UsersAccess(dbMock.Object);
    //Act
    userAccess.SaveLocation(It.IsAny<User>());
    //Assert
    dbMock.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
}
```

Precisely this line of code

```
dbMock.Setup(x => x.Users.SingleOrDefault(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>)).Returns(new User());
```

I create a test for this method here:

```
public void SaveLocation(User user)
{
    var validUser = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == user.ID);
    validUser.Latitude = user.Latitude;
    validUser.Longitude = user.Longitude;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Right now I get this error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Expression>'

Comment: You need a `()` after the `>>>` from `It.IsAny`. Simple typo.

Comment: You're not going to be able to "Setup" `SingleOrDefault` - it's an extension method, which is unsupported by Moq.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but now I have an error with Returns(new User()));


Error CS1061 'User' does not contain a definition for 'Returns' and no accessible extension method 'Returns' accepting a first argument of type 'User' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)